# Stability theory in the context of $\omega$-stable theories

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, model-theory

I'm looking for some references to get me started on stability theory. More specifically, I want to find sources that talk about notions in stability theory, but for $\omega$-stable theories, which should hopefully be much easier to understand than general stable theories since things should be much nicer. (I guess even starting with strongly minimal theories is acceptable for me.) The thing I care about the most is that it should be as friendly to a beginner (having taken a first course in model theory) as possible, so loss of generality (esp. beyond $\omega$-stability) is no problem to me.

Are there such sources?

Cross-posted from [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4682004/stability-theory-in-the-context-of-omega-stable-theories).

Comment: Did you look at Pillay's Geometric Stability Theory?

Comment: Oh, I guess the title was a bit too daunting for a starter in stability theory so I didn't check; I'll go ahead and take a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

David Marker's textbook "Model Theory: An Introduction" largely focuses on $\omega$-stable theories. You may already be familiar with the material from chapters 1 to 4, and you can probably omit chapter 5, but chapters 6, 7, 8 are about $\omega$-stability.

Pillay's Geometric Stability Theory is better read after reading Marker or something equivalent.